# No Programs, or Windows Explorer shows .FBX files

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Nothing, nothing at all shows up when i try to find my .FBX file. And yes. I am sure it is the right place.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the view options in explorer.

Run explorer.

Hit "Alt" key, select "Tools"-"Folder Options"-"View"-"Hidden files and folders"-> show